# Questions on using synchronized and Transaction Management together

Tags: java, transactions

I was doing a code review and I found a code piece like below where a Java method **processDataInTransaction** uses both S**ynchronized and Transaction Management together** and makes a call to **createOrUpdateGroupData** method

```
  private synchronized void processDataInTransaction(final Map<String, List<ListGroup>> groupMap,
            final GroupMetadata grpMetadata)
    {
        TransactionDefinition transactionDefinition = new DefaultTransactionAttribute(
                TransactionDefinition.PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW);

        new TransactionTemplate(transactionManager, transactionDefinition)
                .execute(new TransactionCallbackWithoutResult()
                {
                    @Override
                    protected void doInTransactionWithoutResult(TransactionStatus status)
                    {
                        createOrUpdateGroupData(groupMap, grpMetadata);
                    }
                });
    }

    // createOrUpdateGroupData

        protected void createOrUpdateGroupData (Map<String, List<ListGroup>> map,
                                                GroupMetadata grpData) 
{  // Code omitted for clarity

}
```

Now my questions are

1. can I not simply put **@Transactional on processDataInTransaction** and **remove synchronized** ?
2. and **use @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.MANDATORY)** on **createOrUpdateGroupData** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer depends on the following.

- Synchronized make sure that the method processDataInTransaction will be synchronized in an  multithreaded context, if there is no concurency execution of your method then you can remove the syncronized.
- if you want to use @Transactionnal, make you that your service is enhanced via AOP, if that is the case, then you can go for @Transactional.

Last thing,   as createOrUpdateGroupData is a protected method, the proxy pattern might not take effect; so use @Scope(proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS ) to make sure that internal method call are proxied.

Comment: When you are spawning a thread for every call to createOrUpdateGroupData method  then why you want to make the method synchronized. Making the method synchronized will not limit the number of threads in any way.

Comment: Absolutely! if you dont need synchronized bloc, you can remove as it can alson slow your code.